# How to yield an instance method from another file for Rspec

Tags: ruby

The code below checks to see if in the file '08_book_titles' I have reversed the string that is in the class Book and method title contained in the code below.  That string being "inferno".

```
require '08_book_titles'

describe Book do

before do
@book = Book.new
end

describe 'title' do
it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
@book.title = "inferno"
@book.title.should == "Inferno"
end
```

I tried the following to no avail.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
class Book
def title
return yield.capitalize
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the capitalized form, then

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def title=( title )
    @title = title.capitalize
  end
end
```

If you want to preserve the original form
﻿

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def title
    @title.capitalize
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, it worked perfect.  I tried looking for resources to learn about this specific thing.  Are there any you could link?